# Распарсить строчку на составляющие

Tags: php, парсер

Не понимаю как  разпарсить строчку указанную ниже на переменные, для дальнейщего применения .

> Анальгин обычный капсулы 300 мг, 20 шт.

- $name = "Анальгин"
- $type ="обычный"
- $dosage = "капсулы 300мг"
- $count    = "20 шт"

P.S Подходящих тем не нашел

Comment: Конкретнее опишите задачу

Comment: Судя по всему еще названия будут с разным количеством слов? если так - то никак=)

Comment: Если регуляркой, решение в лоб: https://regex101.com/r/zwLKfa/1 :)

Comment: Если вы собираетесь решать эту задачу в общем случае, то приведите все возможные варианты названий. Вместо капсул наверное могут быт таблетки, например. Возможно, могут быть и ампулы, тогда объем будет в мл а не мг. и т.п.

Comment: Мало данных, приведите еще примеры строк для распарсивания

Answer (score 0):

Можно так: $a = explode (" ", $str);

Comment: мне почему-то кажется, что при таком решении `капсулы 300мг` и `20 шт` будут разбиты на разные элементы массива

Comment: Так и есть, каждое слово будет элементом массива.

Comment: да но ничего же не мешает, взять после два элемента массива, просто если есть более конкретная задача, то опишите ее

Comment: Прочитайте условие задачи, как считаете ваш ответ и правда сделает то, что просит автор?

Comment: В задаче указана 1 строка, поэтому я и прошу больше конкретики

Comment: Вот какой массив получается на выхлопе , после фильтрации , нужных мне товаров . https://i.imgur.com/Ba9Q8cb.png . Мне элемент массива с ключом $name надо разбить на переменные которые в главной задаче $name , $type  и т.д.

Comment: В данном случае регулярными выражениями так же не получится

Answer (score 0):

Можно распарсить с помощью регулярных выражений

```
$str = 'Анальгин обычный капсулы 300 мг, 20 шт.';

preg_match_all('~\pL+(?:\s\d+\s\pL+\S)?|\d+\s\pL+\S~u', $str, $arr);
list($name, $type, $dosage, $count) = $arr[0];

echo "$name $type $dosage $count";
```